# Why doesn't wkhtmltopdf page-break-after have any effect?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf 0.10.0 rc2 for Mac

I have an html like this one :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
      .break{
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        page-break-after: always;
        border :1px solid red
      }
      .page-breaker {
      display: block;
      page-break-after: always;
      border :1px solid red
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container break">
      page 1
    </div>
    <div class="page-breaker"></div>
    <div class="container">
      page 2
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I simply try :

```
wkhtmltopdf test.html test.pdf
```

But it didn't produce a page-break, I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I'm using wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9 on OSX, and for me, your markup produces a 3-page PDF. Page 1 is the words 'page 1' surrounded by a red box, page 2 is a plain red line (empty div page-breaker), and page 3 is the words 'page 2' with no outline.

Comment: You're right it work correctly with wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9

Comment: Working correctly with `wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc2` here as well (Win 7).

Comment: Doesn't work in 0.12.0

Comment: @Nenotlep I don't see 0.11.0 RC2 or 0.12.0, links?

Comment: @PhillPafford There is some kind of strange issue with the version numbers. When I get `wkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-installer.exe` From https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ and install it and then run `wkhtmltopdf.exe --version` I get `wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc2`. So that's the version I meant. Sorry for the confusion, but I don't know what to call the version :)

Comment: As for 0.12.0, this is the first I have heard of one and I don't know where to search for it either.

Comment: Works with `wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc1` on Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: I had similar issues. Got it to work by using page-break-before:always instead. You could try to apply it to the second page and see if it helps.

Comment: Same issue with 0.12.0 but worked fine 0.11.0 rc1

Comment: Doesn´t work in 0.9.2 but works in 0.12.2.1

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Possibly unrelated as your pdf generated ok with an earlier version of wkhtmltopdf. Either way, I had similar issues with page breaks not being applied correctly. My problem was parent elements of the page-breaked element having an `overflow` other than `visible`.
This fixed my issue:

```
* {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Of course, you can be more specific about the tags this applies to ;)

Comment: Thanks to add more info to this. ;)

Comment: You're a true hero :)

Comment: Floats can also cause this problem, which can be fixed with `float: none`.

Comment: I cannot believe that this is what it took to make it happen. Thanks!

Comment: You are a man!!! thanks a lot. If I can give you gold or something, reputation let me know.

Answer (score 31):

try using as follows

```
 <div style="page-break-before:always;">
   //your content
</div>
```

this should work.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Using CSS did not work, but put right in the first div of the new page worked.

Comment: this worked for me, using the latest wkhtmltopdf 0.12.  My guess is it doesn't fully render the CSS before it decides where the page breaks are, kind of annoying.

Answer (score 15):

I am usinf wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.2

For me  page-break-after works when a border is set, and when the breaker div is an **immediate child of body**.

```
.page-breaker {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    border :1px solid transparent;
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

*break-break-before* does not work.

*--print-media-type* not needed.

Comment: This worked for me, I didn't need the border but I had to ensure that the element I was using for the break was an immediate child of the body

Answer (score 4):

I am using version wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0

For me, page breaks ONLY work with --print-media-type.
Without it, page break protection for images works, but not page-break-after or before.

I had to make a special css file for print media to get it work.

Setting the paper size to 'A3' or using the 'overflow: visible' didn't make any difference.

Also see [WKHTMLTOPDF with pdfkit on Rails ignoring table page breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193481/wkhtmltopdf-with-pdfkit-on-rails-ignoring-table-page-breaks)

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine after remove media print

**Before:**

```
@media print {
    .page-break { height:0;page-break-after: always; margin:0; border-top:none;}
}
```

above code not working in new version.

**Now**

```
.page-break { height:0;page-break-after: always; margin:0; border-top:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the wkhtmltopdf to version 0.12.5. Page break issue not occuring for me after updating.

Use `--disable-smart-shrinking` to avoid empty white space ( If you have any)

Use `--zoom <value>` to avoid page page (If entire page not showing)